# Return View/Redirect To Action does nothing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following method in my GameController.cs

```
        public ActionResult Index(bool newgame, int gameId)
    {
        if (newgame)
        {
            game = new Game();
            game.Characters = AddCharacters();
            game.Player1 = (User)Session["User"];
            game.Key = getKey();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
        //else
        //{
        //    game = new Game();
        //    GetChat();
        //    GetCharacters();
        //    //game.Player1 = ?(DB)
        //    game.Player2 = (User)Session["User"];
        //    //Index();
        //}
        ViewGame Vgame = new ViewGame(game);

        int p1Char = rnd.Next(1, 23);
        int p2Char = p1Char;

        do
        {
            p2Char = rnd.Next(1,23);
        }
        while (p2Char == p1Char);

        Vgame.Player1.Character = Vgame.Characters[p1Char];

        CreateGame(Vgame.Key, Vgame.Player1.Character, Vgame.Characters[p2Char]);

        return View(Vgame);
    }
```

Everything works in this method, except the RedirectToAction, it just doesn't do anything.. No error message, no warnings, no crashes, just nothing. I also tried to replace it with "Return View();" but that doesn't work either, while I do have a view in Views>Game>Index.cshtml

Probably something big I missed, but I can't seem to find it.

```
@model GuessWho.Models.ViewGame
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Guess Who?!";
    int i = 0;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="containerGame">
        <div id="upperRow">
            <div id="TitleText">
                <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="players">
                <div class="player mr">
                    <div class="image">
                    </div>
                    <p>@Model.Player1.Username</p>
                </div>
                <div class="player">
                    <div class="image">
                    </div>
                    <p>@Model.Player1.Username</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="gameField">
            @foreach (var item in Model.Characters)
            {
                <div class="char" id="@i" onclick="ShowDropDown(this.id)">
                    <img src="~/Content/Images/Characters/@item.ImageSource" class="character" alt="Character" />
                    <img src="~/Content/Images/Cross.png" class="cross" alt="Cross" />
                    <p>@item.Name</p>
                </div>
                i++;
            }
            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#" onclick="Flip()">Flip</a>
                <a href="#">Guess</a>
                <a href="#" onclick="Highlight()">Highlight</a>
                <a href="#" class="red" onclick="Hide()">Hide</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="chatBox">
            @foreach (var item in Model.Chat)
            {
                <div class="chat">
                    <p class="sender">@item.Sender.Username:</p>
                    <p class="message">@item.Message</p>
                    <p class="time">@item.Time</p>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <div id="sendBox">
            <div class="chatContent" style="display: none;">
                <input type="button" class="YesNoBtn" value="Yes" id="yesButton" onclick="Send(this)" />
                <input type="button" class="ml YesNoBtn" value="No" id="noButton" onclick="Send(this)" />
            </div>
            <div class="chatContent">
                <textarea id="message" class="ChatField" placeholder="Send a chat.."></textarea>
                <input type="button" id="sendmessage" class="SendBtn" value="Send" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="myChar" onclick="ToggleChar()">
            <div id="header">
                <p>My Character</p>
            </div>
            <div class="char" id="current">
                <img src="~/Content/Images/Characters/@Model.Player1.Character.ImageSource" class="character" alt="Character" />
                <p>@Model.Player1.Character.Name</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**MenuController.cs**

```
        public ActionResult CreateGame()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Game", new { newgame = true, gameId = 0 });
    }
```

and in Index.cshtml of my MenuController:

```
            $('#createGame').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("CreateGame", "Menu")',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (result) {
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean _it just doesn't do anything_? And why are you redirecting to the same method? And you are passing a model back to the method which does not accept a model.

Comment: Like I said in my question, I already tried Return View() so this was just me trying stuff

Comment: And what are you claiming does not work when you use `return View(...)`?

Comment: The view "Index" to be returned

Comment: What does CreateGame() do ?

Comment: Please load Chrome. In Developer Tools, goto Network and select `Preserve log`. Load the above URL. Please share with us the entries from the Network tab.

Comment: Also please update your question to show your attempt using `return View(...`.

Comment: what you've shown using View(Vgame) ought to work fine, assuming your view is setup correctly. Maybe show us the view code? Also do what mjwills said and check your network entries to see what's actually happening.

Comment: Is there any view for this action? please insert your view code for more details.

Comment: @shaghayeghsheykholeslami the question says " I do have a view in Views>Game>Index.cshtml", so you don't really need to ask that. However you're right, seeing the code for it might help to give clues about the (very vaguely specified) problem.

Comment: @shaghayeghsheykholeslami added my view

Comment: How are you calling your `Index()` method? Are you using ajax?

Comment: I'm calling it from a different controller, which action is triggered by an ajax function yes

Comment: write your code for calling controller please

Comment: Then you need to show your ajax call - ajax calls stay on the same page so you need to update the DOM with the response in its success callback (but returning a view would make no sense - it should be a partial view)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Added those too

Comment: And referring to the other aspect of the question, RedirectToAction will not work via AJAX either...the AJAX client doesn't follow redirect headers (unlike the browser itself with a regular request). You'd have to write code yourself to get the Location header from the response and then make another request to the new URL. But it doesn't really make much sense anyway, as Stephen said, if you're loading things via AJAX you want to be returning partial views or even just JSON data. Returning a whole view makes no sense - you can't embed an entire HTML document into another one.

Comment: Add a `<div id="xx"></div>` to the view that makes your ajax call and modify your ajax code to `success: function (result) { $('#xx').html(result); },` and you will see the `Index.cshtml` view added to it (which is almost certainly not what you want)

Comment: I think I should learn about Ajax before using it.. thank you for your time. I got it to work with a normal call to the controller method

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calling the method via AJAX, you must send a different instruction back than you would if you were using MVC standard via submit button.

Here is an example of sending Redirect back to AJAX call:

**Controller**

```
return Json(new { success = true, url = Url.Action("Index", new { param1 = "example" }) });
```

**View**

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: postUrl,
        data: JSON.stringify(submitData)
    }).done(function (response) {
        if (response.success) {
            window.location.href = response.url;
        } else {
            //something went wrong.
        }

    }).error(function (ex) {
        //something went wrong.
    })
    }
```